# Possible to remove library after a certain android version?

Tags: android

We have a library and we don't want to use it after API level 21 as it adds up in size.
For example:-
We have a QR code scanning library with support back to API level 17, but we want to replace it with CameraX but its support starts from 21.
So basically use CameraX for API 21 onwards and use the old library for everything below 21, without adding the size to the device with newer android versions.

Is there any possibility to do this using AAB?

Comment: While [App Bundle Conditional Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/conditional-delivery) has a min/max SDK API switch, do think about what happens when the OS gets upgraded on device (although since Android 5.0 is so old now, I'm not sure how often OS upgrading would happen in the wild).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks a lot, I got the directing I should be going for. Also, thanks for letting me know about the edge case